# Is it not good to use .php files instead of .html?

Tags: php, web-deployment

I am makeing a php website and I is it not professional to use the .php exstentions as a substitute for .html?

Comment: As this appears to be your first post, you would want to post a code example. Something that we can help you with. Not really for open ended questions like this. I would say it's up to you. I am proud of .php extensions on my site.

Comment: As far as whether or not it is professional, it's really a matter of opinion, but I think most people would not find either extension more professional than the other. The only benefit I have heard of to using .html instead of .php is that it can make it a little more difficult for people to know how to attack your site.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use php, by default, your web server will require that the file ends in .php.
This is perfectly fine for HTML, because PHP will always output HTML.

If you don't want to use .php as file ending in the URL bar, you can look into mod_rewrite for the .htaccess file.

Answer (score -1):

## Solutions

### First

You can use `.php` only as an extension for php files, just to let them be compiled, if not any modification made to the server.

### Second

Try `.htaccess` files, entering this code will allow use of `.html` or any file extension as php executable.

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .txt
```

### There are other ways, sure!

Comment: this is so weird, and PHP is a scripting language, does not require compile.

Comment: used the word compile to site "execution process"